# How does CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION work?

Tags: php, libcurl

What happens when `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is set false? Can the server detect my `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is set false? When I send `GET`/`POST` request, Does `libcurl` send head request or `GET`/`POST` when `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is set false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION** says to Curl request, that should do a redirect if a 304 or similar header is received.

It has nothing to do with server, but **Curl** as client should go further if a redirect response is received.

Comment: It could also be specifically mentioned that the server cannot see if if curl has that option set TRUE or FALSE since it doesn't change the request at all.